# How can I fill nested simple array type json after execution Restsharp?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, json.net

I have a question about data parsing for string json. Actually  I got stuck with something. My json is below after

"**response = clientRest.Execute(request);**" execution.  but In FeaturePreference.cs , **FeaturePreference.Rootobject** is empty . All label = null Value's = 0. Is there something wrong? **stats** values :

[image]

MY Json (response) :

```
[
    {
        "Label": "Spa Merkezi",
        "Value": 3.7037037037037037
    },
    {
        "Label": "Güzellik Merkezi",
        "Value": 0.92592592592592593
    },
    {
        "Label": "Açık Havuz",
        "Value": 4.62962962962963
    },
    {
        "Label": "Yerli İçecek",
        "Value": 0.92592592592592593
    }
]
```

```
    public class FeaturePreference
    {

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public Result[] Result { get; set; }
        }

        public class Result
        {
            public string Label { get; set; }
            public float Value { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

My Entire Code:

```
        private static void DataParseForSomeShit(string userid)
        {

            var clientRest = new RestClient("https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.Resource = $"foobyuserid/?userid={userid}&code=g2ehoC4tycM6H2TcJUWszTlWa6lXfsA==";
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            IRestResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = clientRest.Execute(request);
                string json = "{ \"Result\" : " + response.Content.Trim('"').Replace('\\', ' ') + "}";
                var stats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeaturePreference.Rootobject>(json); // Empthy items !
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Content))
            {

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to manually manipulate the JSON before deserializing to try to fit your model.  Don't do that.  Instead, deserialize into the correct structure that matches your JSON.  Your JSON represents an array of `FeaturePreference.Result`, so you should deserialize into `FeaturePreference.Result[]` (or `List<FeaturePreference.Result>` if you prefer).

Try changing this:

```
string json = "{ \"Result\" : " + response.Content.Trim('"').Replace('\\', ' ') + "}";
var stats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeaturePreference.Rootobject>(json); // Empthy items !
```

To this:

```
var stats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeaturePreference.Result[]>(response.Content);
```